# switch goes through but does not complete operations processing

Tags: function, switch-statement, processing

```java
import processing.serial.*;  // add the serial library 
Serial myPort;        // the serial port to monitor  
PFont f;
PrintWriter output;
int pianoBColor = 0;
int numKeys = 6;
int sizeW = 900;
int sizeH = 830;
int pianoBackgroundW = sizeW*8/9;
int pianoBackgroundH = sizeH/3;
int blackSpace = 30;
int Empty1;
int Empty2;
int whitePressed=20;
int blackPressed = 255;
int whiteUnpressed = 255;
int blackUnpressed = 0;
int divider = 2;
int roundness = 10;
int pianoSpacingH =(sizeH - pianoBackgroundH) ;
int pianoSpacingW = (sizeW-pianoBackgroundW)/2;
int pianoKeyH = pianoBackgroundH - divider*2 ;
int pianoKeyW = (780/numKeys) - divider*8;
int num;

void setup ()
{
  size(900, 830);  // set the window size, will need to hardcode for Processing 3 compatibility
  background(0, 255, 250);
  println(Serial.list());  // list all available serial ports 
  // myPort = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[0], 115200);  // define input port 
  // myPort.clear(); 
  f = createFont("Arial", 50, true);
  RecorderDrawer();
  PianoDrawer();


}

void draw ()
{
delay(1000);
PianoPress(1, 255,200);
println("fr");
delay(1000);
PianoPress(1,0,255);

}

void PianoPress(int num, int blackKeysColor, int whiteKeysColor)
{
  // 1, 8 black key covers the right hand
  // 7, 12  black key covers the left hand
  // 2,4,6,9,11 black keys
  // 3,5,10 white keys covered by both sides
  switch(num)
  { 
  case 1:
    fill (whiteKeysColor);
    println("front");
    rect(pianoSpacingW +divider/2, pianoSpacingH+divider, pianoKeyW, pianoKeyH, roundness) ;
   println("debug");
    fill (blackKeysColor);
    println("back");
    rect(pianoSpacingW +divider/2+divider+pianoKeyW*2/3-2, pianoSpacingH+divider, pianoKeyW/2, pianoKeyH/2, roundness) ;
    println("debug");
    break;

    case 2:
    fill (blackKeysColor);
    println("case2");
    rect(pianoSpacingW +divider/2+divider+pianoKeyW*2/3-2, pianoSpacingH+divider, pianoKeyW/2, pianoKeyH/2, roundness) ;
     delay(100);
    break;

    case 3:
    fill (whiteKeysColor);
    rect(pianoSpacingW +divider/2+pianoKeyW, pianoSpacingH+divider, pianoKeyW, pianoKeyH, roundness) ; 
    fill (blackKeysColor);
    rect(pianoSpacingW +divider/2+pianoKeyW*4/6, pianoSpacingH+divider, pianoKeyW/2, pianoKeyH/2, roundness) ;  
    rect(pianoSpacingW +divider/2+divider+pianoKeyW*10/6, pianoSpacingH+divider, pianoKeyW/2, pianoKeyH/2, roundness) ;  
    break;

     case 4:
    fill (blackKeysColor);
    rect(pianoSpacingW +divider/2+divider+pianoKeyW*10/6, pianoSpacingH+divider, pianoKeyW/2, pianoKeyH/2, roundness) ;  
    break;

     case 5:
    fill (whiteKeysColor);
    rect(pianoSpacingW +divider/2+pianoKeyW*2, pianoSpacingH+divider, pianoKeyW, pianoKeyH, roundness) ; 
    fill (blackKeysColor);
    rect(pianoSpacingW +divider/2+pianoKeyW*16/6+4, pianoSpacingH+divider, pianoKeyW/2, pianoKeyH/2, roundness) ;  
    rect(pianoSpacingW +divider/2+divider+pianoKeyW*10/6, pianoSpacingH+divider, pianoKeyW/2, pianoKeyH/2, roundness) ;  
    break;  

  case 6:
    fill (blackKeysColor);
     println("case6");
    rect(pianoSpacingW +divider/2+pianoKeyW*16/6+4, pianoSpacingH+divider, pianoKeyW/2, pianoKeyH/2, roundness) ;  
    delay(100);
    break;

  case 7:
    fill (whiteKeysColor);
    rect(pianoSpacingW +divider/2+pianoKeyW*3, pianoSpacingH+divider, pianoKeyW, pianoKeyH, roundness) ;
  fill (blackKeysColor);
    rect(pianoSpacingW+pianoKeyW*16/6+4, pianoSpacingH+divider, pianoKeyW/2, pianoKeyH/2, roundness) ;
    break;

case 8:
    fill (whiteKeysColor);
    rect(pianoSpacingW +divider/2+pianoKeyW*4, pianoSpacingH+divider, pianoKeyW, pianoKeyH, roundness) ;
    fill (blackKeysColor);
    rect(pianoSpacingW+pianoKeyW*28/6+9, pianoSpacingH+divider, pianoKeyW/2, pianoKeyH/2, roundness) ;
    break;

  case 9:
    fill (blackKeysColor);
    rect(pianoSpacingW +divider/2+pianoKeyW*28/6+8, pianoSpacingH+divider, pianoKeyW/2, pianoKeyH/2, roundness) ;  
    break;

      case 10:
    fill (whiteKeysColor);
    rect(pianoSpacingW +divider/2+pianoKeyW*5, pianoSpacingH+divider, pianoKeyW, pianoKeyH, roundness) ; 
    fill (blackKeysColor);
    rect(pianoSpacingW +divider/2+pianoKeyW*28/6, pianoSpacingH+divider, pianoKeyW/2, pianoKeyH/2, roundness) ;  
    rect(pianoSpacingW +divider/2+pianoKeyW*34/6+10, pianoSpacingH+divider, pianoKeyW/2, pianoKeyH/2, roundness) ;  
    break;

  case 11:
    fill (blackKeysColor);
    rect(pianoSpacingW +divider/2+pianoKeyW*34/6+10, pianoSpacingH+divider, pianoKeyW/2, pianoKeyH/2, roundness) ;  
    break;

     case 12:
    fill (whiteKeysColor);
     println("case12");
    rect(pianoSpacingW +divider/2+pianoKeyW*6, pianoSpacingH+divider, pianoKeyW, pianoKeyH, roundness) ; 
    fill(blackKeysColor);
    rect(pianoSpacingW+pianoKeyW*34/6+10, pianoSpacingH+divider, pianoKeyW/2, pianoKeyH/2, roundness) ;
     delay(100);
    break;
  }
}


// set up functions
void PianoDrawer()
{
  fill(pianoBColor);
  rect( pianoSpacingW, pianoSpacingH, pianoBackgroundW, pianoBackgroundH, roundness);
  WhiteKeyDrawer();
  BlackKeyDrawer();
}

void WhiteKeyDrawer()
{
  for (int i = 0; i <= numKeys; i = i+1)
  {
    fill (255);
    rect(pianoSpacingW +divider/2+i*pianoKeyW, pianoSpacingH+divider, pianoKeyW, pianoKeyH, roundness) ;
  }
}
void BlackKeyDrawer()
{

  for (int i = 0; i <= numKeys; i = i+1)
  {
    if (i<=3)
    {
      Empty1 = i/3;
    } else
    {
      Empty1 = (i-3)/3;
    }
    Empty2 = i/7;
    println( Empty1, " ", Empty2);
    if (Empty1 == 0 && Empty2 == 0)
    {
      fill (0);
      rect(pianoSpacingW +divider/2+divider*i+pianoKeyW*2/3 + pianoKeyW*i, pianoSpacingH+divider, pianoKeyW/2, pianoKeyH/2, roundness) ;
    }
  }
}

void RecorderDrawer()
{
  fill(255);
  rect( pianoSpacingW-5, blackSpace-5, pianoBackgroundW+10, (sizeH-pianoBackgroundH)-100, roundness); 
  //stroke(255);
  fill(60);
  rect( pianoSpacingW, blackSpace, pianoKeyW*2/3, (sizeH-pianoBackgroundH)-blackSpace-80);
  for (int i = 0; i <= numKeys-2; i = i+1)
  {
    rect( pianoSpacingW+pianoKeyW*2/3+pianoKeyW*i/2, blackSpace, pianoKeyW/2, (sizeH-pianoBackgroundH)-blackSpace-80);
  }
  rect( pianoSpacingW+pianoKeyW*19/6, blackSpace, pianoKeyW*5/6, (sizeH-pianoBackgroundH)-blackSpace-80);
  rect( pianoSpacingW+pianoKeyW*4, blackSpace, pianoKeyW*5/6, (sizeH-pianoBackgroundH)-blackSpace-80);

  for (int i = 0; i <= numKeys-4; i = i+1)
  {
    rect(pianoSpacingW+pianoKeyW*29/6-10 +pianoKeyW*i/2, blackSpace, pianoKeyW/2, (sizeH-pianoBackgroundH)-blackSpace-80);
  }
  rect( pianoSpacingW+pianoKeyW*25/4, blackSpace, pianoKeyW*3/4+2, (sizeH-pianoBackgroundH)-blackSpace-80);       
  fill(100, 20, 200);
  textFont(f);
  textAlign(CENTER);
  text("ARDUINO PIANO PLAYER", sizeW/2, sizeH-pianoBackgroundH-20);
}
```

Hello, I am trying to make a piano keyboard that will record the strokes and time length and play it. I am troubleshooting before going through the rest of the code and appear to have trouble with the pressed key color change. I make it go through a function and based on the switch case change the color of the key. It goes through the code but the processing screen does not go through the color change. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call the `delay()` function from inside the `draw()` function like that. This is causing you to only get 1 frame every 2 seconds, which will definitely mess up your user input.

Instead, either use the `millis()` or the `frameCount` variables to perform time-based actions.